# true usage of onStartCommand in Android

Tags: android, service

I am a little confused. I want to use a Service to register content Observer and prevent from stopping it. Where should I register contentObserver, in onCreate or onStartCommand? in other words, which one of these codes is true:

```
private ContentObserver smsObserver;
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    smsObserver = new ObserverSms(getApplicationContext());
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, smsObserver);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

or

```
private ContentObserver smsObserver;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    smsObserver = new ObserverSms(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, smsObserver);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

or in onStart()?

Does execute onCreate or onStart again each time the page opens with onStartCommand?
and Doesn't the "return" in "return START_STICKY;" cause stop the contentObserver in second codes?

Answer (score 1):

The initialization flow of a service after startService is called:

> Constructor -> onCreate -> onStartCommand

The onStartCommand will be called every time after startService is called.

However the onCreate will be only called once.

Normally, the onCreate is used like the constructor because we usually don't implement the constructor of a service.

And the onStartCommand is to handle every startService request from different packages/processes which are not sure if there is a second startService or not.

In your case, if you only call startService once, they will be the same.

Comment: I didn't understand you. finally which one is correct or better? I want to run observer forever(until user disables it). Now when I use Observer, after a while The observer slows down the phone.

Comment: Where should I register and unregister observer?

Comment: I would suggest you to register it in onStartCommand and deregister it in onDestroy. But remember to handle multiple onStartCommand called if there is not only one startService. Do not register twice.

Comment: Please help to have a comment or choose it as the answer, thanks.